# Single Click navigation in File Browser

Tags: file-browser

I thought this would've been asked many times, but I can't find it. Forgive my novice, but I can't seem to find out how to make the File Browser navigate through folders using a single click. Ex: I want to open a file so I open the file browser. In the last version I had (2.81) I could click a folder and it would automatically open the next level down until I got to the file. For some reason, I opened v2.93 and now I have to double click each folder to get to the next level down. I know it's trivial, but it's so much faster to single click to open. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

From: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/how-to-open-folders-by-a-single-click-in-blender-2-8x/

1. Go to menu *Edit > Preferences > Keymap*.
2. Expand tree node *File Browser > File Browser Main*.
3. Expand *Select* | `Mouse` | `Left Mouse` key-map.
4. Tick the *Open* checkbox.
5. Click *Save Preferences* button in the lower left corner of the preferences window

Comment: Thanks so much, Edy! I like learning more and more about Blender, but it still seems like such a complicated application. Maybe they'll make it more intuitive in years to come.